# how should I reinterpret_cast the this pointer in a const member function?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, reinterpret-cast

I've recently been looking at const-correctness and as I was going through some of my code I noticed thats the

```
this
```

pointer can be cast to a non-const pointer (to seemingly no effect) with reinterpret_cast in Visual Studio.

This is shown below.

```
const uint32_t & T::func() const
{
    return *reinterpret_cast< const uint32_t * const>(this); // This compiles
}

const uint32_t & T::anotherfunc() const
{
    return *reinterpret_cast< const uint32_t * >(this); // This also compiles
}
```

Is there a correct way of doing this or are they both correct?

Also, I thought reinterpret_cast was supposed to stop changing of const keywords?

Sorry if the question seems inconsequential it's just a curiosity I had.

Comment: Both snippets exhibit undefined behavior. `this` doesn't point to an instance of `uint32_t`, whether `const` or otherwise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Wouldn't this be undefined only in the case wherein sizeof(T) < sizeof(int)?

Comment: This looks like it would read the first four bytes of your object as a `uint32_t`.  If the object is smaller than 4 bytes, it could cause problems.

Comment: No. [Type punning](https://adriann.github.io/undefined_behavior.html) is undefined behavior, period.